# How can I build a GUI emacs on OS X?

Tags: osx, build

I've downloaded a copy of GUI emacs from [here](http://emacsformacosx.com/) and have been using it since then, but it crashes pretty often when I have 20+ frames opened. (I don't know if it's also the case for when there are just few frames.) I heard that if you use the version you have built from the source code, it rarely crashes. How can I do that for a GUI emacs? Can I build some source code? I tried the terminal version of emacs before, but I learned that there was no way to move the cursor with the simple left clicks in it (It bypasses the left clicks. I could option-click, though). I'd like to move the cursor with clicks kind of frequently, so it should be the GUI version.

Mac OS X Mountain Lion, Emacs 24.5.9.0 (also crashes frequently in 24.4)

Comment: How/where did you get an `Emacs 24.5.90`?  This number either means it's the 90th build of Emacs-24.5 (hopefully noone has to build that many times the same source code) made on the same machine, or means that it's the first pretest for 24.6 (but there's never been such a pretest).

Comment: @Stefan Oh, sorry I forgot to put the dot. Version 24.5 (9.0) is the same as 24.5.9.0, right?

Comment: No, there's no "24.5 (9.0)" nor "24.5.9.0" version of Emacs.  You're probably using some Emacs derivative instead (maybe version 9.0 of that derivative), but I don't recognize it offhand.

Comment: Do you need additional help to build your own without the assistance of homebrew or macports?  My suggestion would be to try out the nightly builds from the same place you linked to in the original question -- click on "Other Versions" -- the most recent as of today is:  **Emacs-2016-01-19_01-41-00-1b76d91…-universal.dmg**

Comment: Looks like this question is targeted for building emacs on OS X. So I made that clarification in the question and tags. Feel free to revert that if that's not the case.

Answer (score 7):

You can easily build from source with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh).  Install Homebrew according to its installation instructions and then type

```
$ brew install emacs --build-from-source --cocoa
```

to install the latest stable Emacs release from source.  `--cocoa` enables the GUI version.

---

However,

> I heard that if you use the version you have built from the source code, it rarely crashes.

this is a myth and nonsense.  Emacs rarely crashes generally, whether you use a binary or build from source.  Building from source will not magically make Emacs more stable.

Frequent crashes of Emacs indicate a deeper problem on your system, such as corrupted memory.